# Exact definition of SAT problem in S4

Tags: computational-complexity, modal-logic, kripke-models

I kind of know what SAT problem is and I need the exact formal description of this problem for S4 logic.
I am trying to prove this problem is PSPACE-Complete!
Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem

Comment: Thank you very much.
But don't you agree that in different logical systems we have different details and exact formal definitions for this problem?
I have some problems to find that and I want to be sure about that...
And besides I need some help to prove that the problem belongs to a certain class of complexity and I couldn't find it anywhere else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!

In general, if we are given a logic $\mathcal{L}$ (which includes a notion of semantics), we can ask the $\mathcal{L}\mathsf{SAT}$ problem<sup>1</sup>:

> If you give me a $\mathcal{L}$-formula $\phi$, is there a model $\mathfrak{M}$ which thinks that $\phi$ is true?

A *solution* for $\mathcal{L}\mathsf{SAT}$ takes in a formula $\phi$ as input and either outputs a model $\mathfrak{M} \models \phi$ or outputs a ($\mathcal{L}$-)proof that $\phi$ is *not* satisfiable.

So in your case, a solution to the $\mathsf{S4~SAT}$ problem takes in a sentence
in $\mathsf{S4}$ and either outputs

- a (reflexive and transitive) model $\mathfrak{M}$ with a world $w \in \mathfrak{M}$ so that $(\mathfrak{M},w) \models \phi$
- an $\mathsf{S4}$ proof of $\lnot \phi$

The classic reference for proving $\mathsf{PSPACE}$ hardness of this problem is
Ladner's paper "The computational complexity of provability in systems of modal propositional logic".

<sup>1</sup>: There is *definitely* a law school joke to be made here...

---

I hope this helps ^_^